# Drupal: embed contact form from contact module directly into template (rather then as a stand alone "page")

Tags: drupal-7, customization, php-5.3, drupal-contact-form

Full disclosure; I'm a complete newbie to Drupal development.

I've been tasked with embedding a contact form in the footer component of our site's template. I've been told to use the Drupal Contact module for this task. The problem is, I don't see how this is possible without dramatically altering the contact module itself. Is there any way to embed the Drupal Contact Module's form in a template; rather than have it as a standalone page? Any constructive input is greatly appreciated.

I'd also be open to any other way of embedding a form directly in a Drupal template.

Thanks, Frank

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to accomplish that by adding the following code into your theme's template.php file:

```
function mytheme_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  module_load_include('inc', 'contact', 'contact.pages');
  $variables['contact_form'] = drupal_get_form('contact_site_form');
}
```

Then in your page template file(s) you can output it with the following code snippet:

```
<?php print render($contact_form); ?>
```

Don't forget to replace 'mytheme' with your actual theme's name and clear the caches.

Answer (score 0):

Frank, 
The following worked for me, I placed it directly in my template.

`require_once drupal_get_path('module', 'contact') .'/contact.pages.inc';
      print drupal_render(drupal_get_form('contact_site_form'));`

[source](https://drupal.org/node/335020#comment-5686982)